# Collection properties should be read only - Loophole?

Tags: c#, oop, code-analysis

In the process of adhering to code analysis errors, I'm changing my properties to have private setters. Then I started trying to understand *why* a bit more. From some research, MS says [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327.aspx):

> A writable collection property allows a user to replace the collection with a completely different collection.

And the answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554566/c-sharp-code-analysis-2227-confusion), states:

> Adding a public setter on a `List<T>` object is dangerous.

But the *reason* why it's dangerous is not listed. And that's the part where I'm curious.

If we have this collection:

```
public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
```

Why make the setter private? Apparently we don't want client code to *replace* the collection, **but if a client can remove every element, and then add whatever they want, what's the point**? Is that not the same as replacing the collection entirely? How is value provided by following this code analysis rule?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not exposing the setter prevents a situation where the collection is assigned a value of `null`. There's a difference between `null` and a collection without any values. Consider:

`for (var value in this.myCollection){ // do something`

When there are no values (i.e. someone has called `Remove` on every value), nothing bad happens. When `this.myCollection` is null, however, a `NullReferenceException` will be thrown.

Code Analysis is making the assumption that your code doesn't check that `myCollection` is null before operating on it.

It's probably also an additional safeguard for the thread-safe collection types defined in `System.Collections.Concurrent`. Imagine some thread trying to replace the entire collection by overwritting it. By getting rid of the public setter, the only option the thread has is to call the thread-safe `Add` and `Remove` methods.

Answer (score 2):

If you're exposing an IList (which would be better practice) the consumer could replace the collection with an entirely different class that implements IList, which could have unpredictable effects. You could have subscribed to events on that collection, or on items in that collection that you're now incorrectly responding to.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to SimpleCoder's null checking (which is, of course, important), there's other things you need to consider.

- Someone could replace the List, causing big problems in thread safety
- Events to a replaced List won't be sent to subscribers of the old one
- You're exposing much, much more behavior then you need to. For example, I wouldn't even make the getter public.

To clarify point 3, don't do `cust.Orders.clear()`, but make a function called `clearOrders()` instead.

What if a customer isn't allowed to go over a credit limit? You have no control over that if you expose the list. You'd have to check that (and every other piece of business logic) every place where you might add an order. Yikes! That's a lot of potential for bugs. Instead, you can place it all in an `addOrder(Order o)` function and be right as rain.

For almost every (I'd say every, but sometimes cheating feels good...) business class, every property should be private for get and set, and if feasible make them readonly too. In this way, users of your class get only behaviors. Protect as much of your data as you can!

Comment: I have to say I disagree somewhat. Exposing a property with generic collection type is quite nice, because it namespaces behaviors related to that collection under a single property. That is to say the base type doesn't get cluttered up with `Myclass.ClearOrders`, `MyClass.AddOrder`, `MyClass.RemoveOrder`, `MyClass.GetOrder` and so  forth. It is also very useful for the person on the other end who wants to iterate over the collection in creative ways. A better alternative would be to write a collection type that only exposes the behaviors you want, and expose an instance of this in a property.

Comment: I don't want other classes iterating over my data in "creative" ways. I want them doing it over my data in the exact ways I specified so that I have control over the business logic. If I expose `orders` as a property, I instantly lose control over validating orders. For instance: let's say if you order over $10,000 , you get a 10% discount. You make 4 orders each of $3,000. You're at $12,000 so you qualify for the discount. If one order is removed, that discount has to disappear from all the orders. If you expose `orders`, that logic becomes significantly more difficult (impossible) to manage.

Comment: No it doesn't. You add that logic to your custom collection type.

Answer (score 1):

[ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) and [ReadOnlyObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668620.aspx) exists only for read only collection scenearios.

`ReadOnlyObservableCollection` is very useful for one way binding in WPF/Silverlight/Metro apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Customer class with a List Property then this property should always have a private setter else it can be changed from outside the customer object via:

```
customer.Orders = new List<Order> 
//this could overwrite data.
```

Always use the add and remove methods of the collection.

The Orders List should be created inside the Customer constructor via:

```
Orders = new List<Order>();
```

Do you really want to check everywhere in your code wether the `customer.Orders != null` then operate on the Orders?

Or you create the Orders property in your customer object as suggested and never check for `customer.Orders == null` instead just enumerate the Orders, if its count is zero nothing happens...